# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'many'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

While trying to return a query-set using generic views, I get an error

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'many'

I am unable to understand the source of this error as it seems to be originating from internal libraries. I have no clue as to why this error originated as the create API works just fine.

**Complete StackTrace**

```
System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
July 16, 2018 - 13:25:43
Django version 1.11.7, using settings 'BirthdayPostStash.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
<QuerySet [<Photos: 1>, <Photos: 2>, <Photos: 3>, <Photos: 4>, <Photos: 5>, <Photos: 6>, <Photos: 7>, <Photos: 8>, <Photos: 9>, <Photos: 10>, <Photos: 11>, <Photos: 12>]>
Internal Server Error: /photos/list-photo/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/t2b/env/bpstash/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/t2b/env/bpstash/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/t2b/env/bpstash/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/t2b/env/bpstash/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/t2b/env/bpstash/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/t2b/env/bpstash/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 489, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/t2b/env/bpstash/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 449, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/t2b/env/bpstash/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 486, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/t2b/env/bpstash/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 201, in get
    return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/t2b/env/bpstash/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 44, in list
    serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
  File "/home/t2b/env/bpstash/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 112, in get_serializer
    return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/t2b/env/bpstash/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 1774, in __init__
    super(ModelField, self).__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'many'
[16/Jul/2018 13:25:45] "GET /photos/list-photo/ HTTP/1.1" 500 111194
```

**models.py**

```
class Photos(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="photos_owner")
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(
              Person,
              related_name="photos_participants",
              null=True,
              blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
class ListPhoto(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = PhotoPublicSerializer
    model = Photos

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.all()
```

**serializer.py**

```
class PhotoPublicSerializer(serializers.ModelField):
    participants = PersonPublicSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Photos
        fields = '__all__'
```

**personserializer.py**

```
class PersonPublicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Looks like it was a typo after all.

```
class PhotoPublicSerializer(serializers.ModelField):
class PhotoPublicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
```

Weird things brain does when it's tired. xD

Comment: Thanks mate, I got the same issue.

Answer (score 11):

I got this issue when `serializer_class` was pointed to the model instead of `ModelSerializer`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is caused by line:

`participants = PersonPublicSerializer(many=True)`

Investigating, can be seen that:

- `PersonPublicSerializer` is a `class` that extends from `serializers.ModelField`
- `serializers.ModelField` is a `class` that extends from `serializers.Field`
- `Field`, when initialized, accepts one of these args (with their defaults):

  - `read_only=False`
  - `write_only=False`
  - `required=None`
  - `default=empty`
  - `initial=empty`
  - `source=None`
  - `label=None`
  - `help_text=None`
  - `style=None`
  - `error_messages=None`
  - `validators=None`
  - `allow_null=False`
- In turn `ModelField` **expects** (that is, it is mandatory to have) a `model_field` argument and can additionally be called with either one of `Field`'s args.

Now, as you can see, neither `ModelField` nor `Field` has a `many` arg in their declaration.

So, either `PersonPublicSerializer` was not declared correctly and should implement a `many` arg, or you're relying on a misunderstanding.

Source: [`Field`'s source code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py#L308)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you suggested, I removed 'many' argument, set read_only=True in arguments and still get the same error. Also I have updated my question and added PersonPublicSerializer definition there. Kindly take a look at it.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I provided wrong serializer_class.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33384912)